# How do I save a file on iPhone from a responsive web site

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web, responsive

I have a responsive web site. User completes a form which creates a PDF file. There is no option on iPhone device to save the file. It only open in preview. There no issue on Android.

How can the user download the file on iOS or icloud /dropbox etc from my responsive site on iPhone

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari does not allow File Download on iPhone. So  you have no Chance. You can only display

Comment: Thank you. but how would recommend saving a file to icloud etc from responsive web on iOS

Comment: seems that also not possible.Due to restrictions in iOS saveAs opens in a new window instead of downloading

Answer (score 0):

To save the pdf, the user could take a screenshot, select "full page", tap done then press "save pdf to files". [This article](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/save-a-safari-web-page-a-pdf-ios/) explains how.

Comment: Thanks.. but I don't see the "full page" nor save to PDF.. I see "save to photo","save to files" and "delete Screenshot".

Comment: It works just fine on ios 13.5 release and public beta. [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPRC4LanQyc) should help you. If it still doesn't work get your users to use something like [this](https://readdle.com/pdfconverter/how-to-convert-web-pages) app.